# Test unit: sidekiq worker doesn't look in test database

Tags: ruby-on-rails, testing, sidekiq

I'm trying to learn TestUnit testing - so this question may be silly.  Sorry in advance...

I have a model called PathState which has an `execute` method which calls a sidekiq worker to do some work.  The sidekiq worker receives the PathState object id, then looks up the PathState, then attempts to perform the `path_state.action` (a string).  When I run the test I always see:

```
Couldn't find PathState with 'id'=980190977
```

That id *is* present, in the test database.  But it looks like sidekiq is looking for it in the development database.

I tried starting sidekiq with -e test, but it still doesn't look in the test database.

What am I doing wrong?

here's database.yml:

```
default: &default
  adapter: mysql2
  encoding: utf8
  pool: 5
  username: rails
  password: secret
  socket: /var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock

development:
  <<: *default
  database: raws_development

test: &test
  <<: *default
  database: raws_test

production:
  <<: *default
  database: raws_production
  username: raws
  password: <%= ENV['RAWS_DATABASE_PASSWORD'] %>
```

here's the test in question:

```
  test "should execute action when executed" do
    ps = PathState.create(:name => "TestName", :action => "touch/tmp/PathStateTest")
    ps.execute
    result = `[ -f /tmp/PathStateTest ] && echo 0 || echo 1`
    assert result==0, "OOPS! PathState doesn't execute action when executed!"
  end
```

and here's #perform of the sidekiq worker:

```
  def perform(path_state_id)
    ps = PathState.find(path_state_id)

    @result = `#{ps.action} 2>&1`
    unless $?.exitstatus.zero?
      # failed state
      Sidekiq.logger.warn "---> PathStateRunner worker failed action: '#    {ps.action}'"
    end
  end
```

Comment: I'd like to see your database.yml, I suspect you are referencing the same one in both env.

Comment: added database.yml plus some other code

Answer (score 0):

It seems like this is problem described in their [FAQ](https://github.com/mperham/sidekiq/wiki/FAQ#why-am-i-seeing-a-lot-of-cant-find-modelname-with-id12345-errors-with-sidekiq).

If your functionality is somehow connected to [`ActiveRecord`s `after_commit`](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_callbacks.html) *hook*, the [`test_after_commit`](https://github.com/grosser/test_after_commit) `gem` may help you!

Good luck!

Comment: no, I don't think so - `ps = PathState.create` creates the object, `ps.execute` causes the sidekiq job to run - well after the PathState object is created.  I don't know how to delay the execution of the sidekiq job any further logically.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to run my Sidekiq workers in my cucumber test by adding the appropriate require statement in support/env.rb:

```
require 'sidekiq/testing'
```

Then I wrote a feature that read something like this:

```
When I do something which adds a job to a queue
Then I should see "Your jobs were added to the queue."
When I wait for the jobs to complete
Then the completed jobs are listed on the page
```

So now, the jobs will be enqueued and executed when it hits the 3rd line in the scenario.
Its definition should be like,

```
When(/^I wait for the jobs to finish$/) do
  MySpecialWorker.drain
end
```

**Also, all the jobs will be run against the test DB**